# ng-class not working from boolean property

Tags: angular

I have two classes, `header-large` and 'header-normal'.  I want to be able to programatically switch between these values based on a boolean property on my component.

I have looked at the `ngClass` documentation and I tried adding these properties to component:

```
public largeHead : boolean = false;
public normalHead : boolean = true;
```

and then use ngClass like:

```
<div id="header" ng-class="{'header-large': largeHead, 'header-normal': normalHead}" class="container-fluid text-center">
```

This doesn't work.  The ng-class statement is just output as it is in HTML and no class is added.

I also tried:

```
<div id="header" ng-class="{'header-large': 'largeHead == true', 'header-normal': 'normalHead == true'}" class="container-fluid text-center">
```

And that doesn't do anything either.  No error messages to go on.

I can't see what I have done wrong.  Is there a different way I should be accessing property?

edit:

The ng-class is not being interpreted.  I tried `ng-class="{'header-large': true}"` and it still doesn't work.

What modules need to be imported for ng-class to work?  I couldn't see anything listed in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing Angular (v2+) then the syntax is `[ngClass]="..."`.  The examples look like the previous version of AngularJS.

**update**: Angular (v2+) documentation for `ngClass`: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I was looking in Angular 2 docs but must have been looking in angular 1.